# Mform SELECT - Moodle

Tags: moodle

Is there mform select tag, when option is selected so that it highlights and stick to the selected one and select more options without the use of control key to select. I tried with selectMulitple, where it allows holding control key to select the options.

```
$select = $mform->addElement('select', 'course', get_string('course', 'core_course'), $options);
        $mform->addHelpButton('course', 'course', 'core_course');
        $mform->addRule('course', null, 'required', null, 'client');
        $mform->setType('course', PARAM_INT);   
        $select->setMultiple(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is no. You need to use the control key to select multiple items in a select.

You could use a series of checkboxes though, something like this:

```
$courses = core_course_category::get(0)->get_courses(
    array('recursive' => true, 'sort' => array('fullname' => 1)));

foreach ($courses as $course) {
    $mform->addElement('advcheckbox', "courses[{$course->id}]",
        format_string($course->fullname), null, array('group' => 1));
}
$this->add_checkbox_controller(1);
```

Then in your edit code, use something like this

```
for each($formdata->courses as $courseid => $selected) {
    if ($selected) {
        // User selected this course.
    } else {
        // User unselected this course.
    }
}
```